# How to make Spring kafka client distributed

Tags: spring, solr, apache-kafka, distributed

I have messages coming in from Kafka. So I am planning to write a listener and "onMessage". I want to process it and push it in to `solr`.

So my question is more architectural, like I have worked on web apps all my career, so in big data how to deploy the spring `kafka` listener, so I can process thousands of messages a second.

1. How do I make my spring code use multiple nodes to distribute the
   load?
2. I am planning to write a `SpringBoot` application to run in
   a tomcat container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the same group id for all instances, different partitions will be assigned to different consumers (instances of your application).

[image]

So, be sure that you specified enough partitions in the topic you are going to consume.

Comment: Thank you. I will try this.